# send email notification using pre_save

Tags: python, django

Hello I am learning python/django
how can I send email notification using using pre_save

I have a task form and assign to dropdown with all users. I want to send them email when they are assigned to a task

here is views.py

```
@login_required
def lead(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = LeadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            lead_record = form.save(commit=False)
            lead_record.user = request.user
            lead_record.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('leads:list')
    else:
        form = LeadForm()

    return render(request, 'leads/form.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
task_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
description = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
is_important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
completion_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
assign_to = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.task_name
```

email

```
send_mail(
           subject = 'New task',
           message = 'You have been assigned to a task',
           from_email = "noreply@gmail.com",
           recipient_list=[Job.assign_to.email]
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `pre_save` signal you would need to register the signal somewhere where  it can discovered.

There are two ways to register it using the `pre_save.connect` method in the signal or using the `django.dispatch.receiver` decorator. [Docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals)

Since using `connect` works for versions before 1.7 I'll cover that one.

By registering the signal in the `models.py` file it can be discovered:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

# The arguments this function receives are defined by the `pre_save` signal.
def send_task_email(sender, instance, raw, using, update_fields):
    # The logic to send the email goes here. e.g.
    return send_mail(
        subject='New task',
        message = 'You have been assigned to a task',
        from_email = "noreply@gmail.com",
        recipient_list=[instance.assign_to.email]
    )

# Register the pre_save signal with the Job model.
# Please note the `dispatch_uid` kwarg to avoid signal duplication.
pre_save.connect(send_task_email, sender=Job, dispatch_uid="sending_email_uid")
```

As a final note: Signals will block the execution until they are completed, sending email is a good candidate to be implemented as a background task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EmailMultiAlternatives of django package to send email.

the module can be imported as:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
```

and then your send function can accomodate this line in order to send email

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email,recipients_list)
msg.send()
```